# Copying one entity into another entity for caching purposes

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am using a cache table to store items back from an api its a simple table of about 20 fileds I am doing it like the following.

```
/// <summary>
/// Store the relationship in sql lite database this will be our cache
/// </summary>
/// <param name="realtionship"></param>
public async void RelationShipCache(Vessels ships) {
        // Get an absolute path to the database file
    VesselsCache newCacheObject = new VesselsCache();
    newCacheObject.IMONumber = ships.IMONumber;
    newCacheObject.IMOCompanyNumber = ships.IMOCompanyNumber;
    newCacheObject.GrossTonnage = ships.GrossTonnage;
    this.VesselsCache.Add(newCacheObject);
    await this.SaveChangesAsync();

}
```

Question is would I be better doing this with Automapper https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html and if so how would I do something as simple as above with that or is that ok to do as I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use automapper here. First, you should determine the source and destination type to work with. From your codes, the `Vessels` is the source type and `VesselsCache` is the destination type. Then, follow the document and the codes is something like below:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Vessels, VesselsCache>());
var mapper = new Mapper(config);
VesselsCache newCacheObject = mapper.Map<VesselsCache>(ships);
```

Don't forget install `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection` from NuGet Package.

Comment: how do i store the content then do i still need to do value a = valueb

Comment: No, automapper helpes you omit this step. The `newCacheObject ` is the same as it in your post. Maybe you can have a try first.